# Range check error when setting TListView Header Font Style

Tags: listview, delphi, winapi, delphi-11-alexandria

In a 32-bit VCL Application in Windows 10 in Delphi 11 Alexandria, I have a `TListView`, where I set the ListView's Header Font Style to BOLD in the FormCreate handler:

```
private
  FhHeaderFont: THandle;

procedure TformMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin  
  ...
  SetColumnHeaderFontBold;
end;

procedure TformMain.SetColumnHeaderFontBold;
const
  LVM_GETHEADER = Winapi.CommCtrl.LVM_FIRST + 31;
var
  LF: Winapi.Windows.TLogFont;
  hHeader, hCurrFont, hOldFont: THandle;
begin
  hHeader := Winapi.Windows.SendMessage(lvMRUProjects.Handle, LVM_GETHEADER, 0, 0);
  hCurrFont := Winapi.Windows.SendMessage(hHeader, WM_GETFONT, 0, 0); // ERangeError

  if GetObject(hCurrFont, SizeOf(LF), Addr(LF)) > 0 then
  begin
    LF.lfWeight := Winapi.Windows.FW_BOLD;
    FhHeaderFont := Winapi.Windows.CreateFontIndirect(LF);
    hOldFont := Winapi.Windows.SelectObject(hHeader, FhHeaderFont);
    Winapi.Windows.SendMessage(hHeader, winapi.Messages.WM_SETFONT, FhHeaderFont, 1);
  end;
end;
```

Now, I RANDOMLY get an `ERangeError` in this line when starting the program:

```
hCurrFont := Winapi.Windows.SendMessage(hHeader, WM_GETFONT, 0, 0); // ERangeError
```

This is the Eurekalog call-stack:

[image]

This is the error message:

```
Range check error at (004EDAED){MyApp.exe} [008EDAED] MainForm.TformMain.SetColumnHeaderFontBold (Line 616, "MainForm.pas") + $13.
```

What is causing this error and how can I avoid it?

Comment: SendMessage takes an `HWND` and not `THandle`. In fact none of your variables should be `THandle`. `SendMessage` returns an `LRESULT` and you probably need to cast that to the correct type for `hCurrFont` which is `HFONT`. Similarly for `hHeader`. So `FhHeaderFont`, `hCurrFont` and `hOldFont` should be `HFONT`. And `hHeader` should be `HWND`. And nothing here shuold be `THandle`.

Comment: `LRESULT` is signed, `THandle` and `HFONT` are unsigned. Such a distinction is made to not have different ranges, and you ignore the different data types largely. Extremely simplified `LRESULT` is `-2.. 2` while `HFONT` is `0.. 4`.

Comment: Can you put this in an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: `SendMessage` returns a `NativeInt`. How should I typecast that?

Comment: I have now redeclared the variables: `hheader: HWND;
  hCurrFont, hOldFont: HFONT;` and typecasted `hHader`: `hCurrFont := Winapi.Windows.SendMessage(HWND(hHeader), WM_GETFONT, 0, 0);` But I am still RANDOMLY getting the same error.

Comment: I've done what you said: https://i.imgur.com/T984AXj.png But I am still getting the same error in the same place.

Comment: Please note that you don't need to define `LVM_GETHEADER` yourself. All the Win32 common control definitions are found in the `CommCtrl` unit (which you mustn't confuse with the `ComCtrls` unit that contains the VCL common control wrappers).

Comment: You have to cast the return value of SendMessage, that's what is missing. It's what is said in sentence 2 of my comment.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks for your help. But for me (who doesn't have your knowledge), your sentence 2 is imprecise, ambiguous, and vague. Could you be more EXPLICIT? Thank you.

Comment: *"cast that to the correct type for hCurrFont which is HFONT"* -> `HFONT(SendMessage(hHeader, WM_GETFONT, 0, 0));`

Comment: Returns an LRESULT could not be more precise. Cast to the correct type is also precise. If you don't know what returns means or what casting is then you should do a bit of revision. I'm sorry if you didn't understand but I think it's reasonable to assume that a program knows what returns means and what casting is.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Your explicitness was the final nail to success. ;-)

Comment: In German, we say "Brett vor dem Kopf" (Engl.: Board in front of the head) when someone doesn't see the obvious in front of him. This is what happened to me. You rationalized this to your perspective, where you have a more profound knowledge of the problematic context, which is a fact. But also a typical psychological game. (see Transactional Analysis).

Comment: I was reacting to your statement that what I said was vague, ambiguous and imprecise. It was none of those things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. You have declared various variables with the wrong type.
2. You sometimes need to use type casts when working with Windows messages.

For the first issue, each variable that you declare as `THandle` is declared incorrectly. `THandle` is used for kernel handles, it is the Delphi type corresponding to `HANDLE` in the Windows C headers. None of the handles in your code is a kernel handle, they are all user mode objects.

`FhHeaderFont`, `hCurrFont` and `hOldFont` should all be declared as `HFONT`. `hHeader` should be declared as `HWND`.

The issue that is causing your range check error is the second one in my list. If you consider what `SendMessage` has to do, it is used for any Windows message. And these messages work with a huge range of different data types. This means that there will sometimes be mismatches between the generic integer types that `SendMessage` accepts and returns, and the types of the variables used for parameters and return values. These mismatches should be dealt with by type casting.

The cause of the range check error is that `SendMessage` returns `LRESULT` which is a signed integer, pointer sized. But `THandle` is an unsigned integer, pointer sized. Even when you correct this by using `HFONT`, then the same error can arise because `HFONT` is also an unsigned integer, pointer sized.

Deal with this by type-casting the return value:

```
hCurrFont := HFONT(Winapi.Windows.SendMessage(hHeader, WM_GETFONT, 0, 0));
```

Likewise you should do the same for the other return value assignment:

```
hHeader := HWND(...);
```

Strictly speaking, it would be best to do the same when passing `FhHeaderFont` as `wParam` in the final call to `SendMessage`. I think I would write that as:

```
Winapi.Windows.SendMessage(hHeader, winapi.Messages.WM_SETFONT, WPARAM(FhHeaderFont), 1);
```

One final note is that `LVM_GETHEADER` is defined in `Winapi.CommCtrl` and should not be re-defined here.

Comment: Thank you for this extensive, explicit, and rational explanation.